# Using UpdateCursor to populate new field based on conditional statement not updating field

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am attempting to populate a new field with a "Y" or "N" based on whether two integer fields are equal.  My code seems like it should work, but when I run it, it does not update the field (the field is still ).  I have double checked that the inputs are correct and I have reloaded the table to make sure it was not an updating issue.

```
inTable = os.path.join(env.workspace, "pivotTableTEMP")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inTable, ["dmready", "total_records", "ALLREADY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == row[1]:
            row[2] == "Y"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            row[2] == "N"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The dmready and total_records fields are both integers and the ALLREADY field is string.

---

Vince's advice worked perfectly for the above code.  However, I added another conditional statement and it is not filling properly.  Here is my new code:

```
inTable = os.path.join(env.workspace, "pivotTableTEMP")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inTable, ["dmready", "total_records", "dm_stat", "ALLREADY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == row[1] and row[2] == "Ready for DM":
            row[3] = "Y"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            row[3] = "N"
            cursor.updateRow(row) # could also delete here if
```

The result of this code is that it fills all records of the ALLREADY field with "N" when there are several that fit the conditions for "Y".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Your assignment statements aren't  -- they're no-op equivalence tests. Use `=` not `==` for assignment.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Can't believe I didn't catch that.  Thank you, Vince!

Comment: You can also structure the logic so the `updateRow` is outside the `if`.  In fact, you can use the ternary logic operator `row[2] = "Y' if row[0] == row[1] else "2"`

Comment: Sounds like you've got some un-handled conditions in the data being tested in the first `if`.  I'd look through the data and make sure you're covering all your bases (spelling variances in "ALLREADY", that sort of thing).

Comment: If you have moved onto a new issue then I suggest researching it as such, and if you remain stuck, then to ask it as a new question.